# Object keep on updating the loop object in java

Tags: java, object, foreach

I am facing a very strange problem in object state updation, what I need to is I need to check if the room code matches put some data in the object and update it into a new blank List object of the HotelRoom object.

The actual problem occurs when I have multiple Search Criteria Object for similar room to book so what the following code is doing that it is updating the following object

```
List<HotelRoom> rooms = newHotel.getRooms();
```

When I check at the end I get all the objects with the similar criteria in the following list.

```
List<HotelRoom> hotelRooms = new ArrayList<HotelRoom>(0);
```

Say if the first criteria is 2 Adults 0 Children, Lead Traveller say Mr. X for first room, and second room criteria is 2 Adults 2 Children, Lead Travller say Mr. Y, when I check the object again I get both the objects same in the above list object i.e. Both objects with 2 Adults 2 Children and Lead Traveller Mr. Y.

```
private void enrichObject(ProductDTO productDTO, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String selectedRoomCode = request.getParameter("selectedRoomCode");
    SearchRequest searchRequest = sessionInterface.getSearchObjectFromSession(request);
    if(searchRequest != null){
        if(productDTO.getHotel() != null && productDTO.getHotel().getRooms() != null && !productDTO.getHotel().getRooms().isEmpty()){
            List<HotelRoom> hotelRooms = new ArrayList<HotelRoom>(0);
            HotelDTO newHotel = productDTO.getHotel();
            List<HotelRoom> rooms = newHotel.getRooms();
            int i = 0;
            for(SearchCriteria criteria : searchRequest.getCriterias()){
                for(HotelRoom room : rooms){
                    HotelRoom newRoom = room;
                    if(room.getProviderRoomId().equals(selectedRoomCode)){

                        String travellerTitle = request.getParameter("travellerTitle" +i);
                        String travellerFirstName = request.getParameter("travellerFirstName" + i);
                        String travellerLastName = request.getParameter("travellerLastName" + i);

                        TravellerDTO travellerDTO = new TravellerDTO();
                        travellerDTO.setLeadTraveller(true);
                        travellerDTO.setTitle(PERSONTITLE.valueOf(travellerTitle));
                        travellerDTO.setFirstName(travellerFirstName);
                        travellerDTO.setLastName(travellerLastName);

                        hotelRooms.add(newRoom);
                        sessionInterface.setLeadTravellerObject(request, travellerDTO);
                        i++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            productDTO.getHotel().setRooms(hotelRooms);
        }   
    }
}
```

So finally my problem is why the object which is enriched inside the inner loop updates the global object as well, which overwrites all my existing objects here as well.

```
List<HotelRoom> hotelRooms = new ArrayList<HotelRoom>(0);
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: @niiraj874u please read the last part of my query.

Comment: which line do you think update all global objects? paste that line here

Comment: I suppose `hotelRooms` is updated because of the line `hotelRooms.add(newRoom);`. What is your expectation? Or maybe you are wanting to have unique rooms only? In which case you should use `HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet` if you want the items to be in the order of insertion.

Comment: do you want to explain your question more simply?

Comment: This part is here because I need to enrich the rooms object with different criteria hence I am updating the newRoom object inside the loop which later I add to hotelRooms.add(newRoom);

Comment: You are not creating a new hotel.. You have the reference to the hotel inside your product dto.. Can you try to create a new hotel instance with the details from product DTO.gethotel() and see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: @prabugp this is not an issue as anyways my enriched objects are overwriting my rooms objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java all the variables are references, so when you do

```
HotelRoom newRoom = room;
```

you are actually just copying the memory address from `room` and it is saved in `newRoom`, so, when you change something in `newRoom` you are also changing `room` because both variables point to the same address.

You can add a `copy()` method (or just implement the `clone()` method) in the HotelRoom class

```
public HotelRoom copy() {
    Room newRoom = new Room();
    newRoom.member0 = this.member0;
    ...
    newRoom.membern = this.membern;
    return newRoom;
}
```

which create a new instance and copy all the members, so, you can safely do `HotelRoom newRoom = room.copy()` and now you will have two variables with the same members but in different memory address, so newRoom won't change the room object. Be careful, if one of your members is another object, you will need to copy (or clone) that member as well

Comment: @Solena thanks a lot for this clear explanation. This solution actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
HotelRoom newRoom = room;
```

You are working on a reference to that `room` after this assignment. You should deep copy the object, then work on the cloned one. You can use `clone()`. You should override clone according to your object structure. You can follow the guidelines in [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/08/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is where you nare facing the issue: `HotelRoom newRoom = room;`

Try `HotelRoom newRoom = new HotelRoom();`
then do `newRoom = room;`

if this doesnt work try populating newRoom using getter setters.

Comment: you are to the point, but your solution is not. Try HotelRoom newRoom = new HotelRoom(); then do newRoom = room;' This expression is same as the pervious one.